# Move membership data from 1.x to 3.x database

Tags: members, upgrade

I have an EE site that's based on the latest 1.x version and that has over 10,000 registered members (I tried a couple times to upgrade to version 2.x but it was a disaster). I now want to rebuild the site from scratch using the latest 3.x version and I want to move my 10k membership from the 1.x database to the 3.x database. Is that possible without creating a bunch of nasty side-effects for the new site?

Answer (score 1):

I would read up on this https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/utilities/member-import.html
Not sure if everyone will have to reset their password or not. ;~}

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wasn't aware of the utility until now. The instructions for how to use the utility are pretty minimal. Would I export from my version 1.x database to a XML file, then import that into the 3.x database? Does the 1.x version software even support the XML format for member data? Any additional info on this is much appreciated!

Comment: I have never actually used the utility. But I would assume, yes, dump your 1.x members table to an xml file, and then import into your ee3 install.
Sometimes these things take a few runs at it to get everything to line up. Most database management tools, like Sequel Pro, can easily export to a varity of, including xml, file types.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Jim! I'll give this a try this weekend.

Comment: Over the weekend I tried the membership utility and learned that it's going to be a bigger job than I thought, but I still think it's the best approach I have to solving my problem. After I've had more time to work with the utility I'll report back again sometime in the next few weeks.